# How can I have discrete rows in a grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I need a layout where the first column has a common `max-content` width across all rows, but the rows are distinct elements as I need to attach event handler to them. So far I can achieve either-or. Can I have both somehow?

```js
for(const el of [...document.getElementsByClassName('row')]) el.onclick=e => {el.style.backgroundColor = 'red'};
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
  background-color: #F0F0FF;
}

.col {
  width: max-content;
}

div {
border: 1px solid red;
margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
Column span
<div class="container">
    <div class="col">323232323232</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>

Row element
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">323232323232</div>
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using a [table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) could solve this problem. Your example code gives me the impression that a table would be a good solution for this. Don't write off the table tag just because you've [heard somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html) you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @Alohci please see update

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes, I thought about it myself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subgrid is now supported cross-browser. I think this is what you might want:

```js
for(const el of [...document.getElementsByClassName('row')]) el.onclick=e => {el.style.backgroundColor = 'red'};
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  background-color: #F0F0FF;
}

.col {
  width: max-content;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">323232323232</div>
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, `subgrid` was on my mind, however I was unable to get it done. Thank you! Its support is a little bit concerning though.

Comment: Support - to me, and my own biased eyes - looks [pretty good](https://caniuse.com/?search=subgrid); do you have many users of IE, Samsung Internet, Opera Mini...? The compatibility does have to meet the needs of your specific site's traffic, but I'd be surprised if the vast majority of your users weren't covered.

Comment: @DavidThomas ... I might have... Apple for example upgrades Safari as part of the firmware. A not-that-old iPad Air 2 is stuck with iOS 15.6, thus Safari 15.6 for example... subgrid support starts with 16...

Answer (score 1):

As someone said, what you want is table layout:

```js
for(const el of [...document.getElementsByClassName('row')]) el.onclick=e => {el.style.backgroundColor = 'red'};
```

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
  background-color: #F0F0FF;
}
.row > * {
  display: table-cell;
}
.row > :not(.col) {
  width: 100%;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">323232323232</div>
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to add `.col { white-space: nowrap; }`. It prevents wrapping of text in the first column, similarly to what `.col { width: max-content; }` does, but "nowrap" is also supported by older browsers.

Comment: If you actually used the tags for a table: `<table><tr><td>...</td></td></table>` , instead of CSS, your code would be even simpler, easier to read, and less error prone.